# How can this regular expression corrected to extract series and image numbers from reports?

Tags: javascript, regex, digits

I'm looking to extract information from the following text examples:

"(series 602 image 91)"
or
" series number 89 and image number 34"
or
"Series # 4, Image # 14" 
and looking to extract 
the numeric as value and series and image tags respectively.

My current attempt:
`([(,]series *{\}d+?[,/ ]* *image* {\}d+(/{\}d+)?[),]) *?   on_img`

Comment: Perhaps use a word boundary and match any char except a digit `\D` inbetween `\bseries \D*(\d+)\D* image \D*(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/eQL9Tx/1

Comment: Can you please try if this helps: (?<=number )[\d]*

Comment: `\bseries \D*(\d+)\D* image \D*(\d+)`
Worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
/series.*?([0-9]+).*?image.*?([0-9]+)/i
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/fBodXP/1). The `.*?` pattern will match any characters between your words, but as few as possible, so the captured numbers will be closest to those words.